# Javascript - jquery ajax post error driving me mad

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, asmx

Can't seem to figure this one out.

I have a web service defined as (c#,.net)

```
[WebMethod]
public string SubmitOrder(string sessionid, string lang,int invoiceno,string email,string emailcc)
{
   //do stuff.
   return stuff;
}
```

Which works fine, when I test it from the autogenerated test thingy in Vstudio.

But when I call it from jquery as

```
$j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wservice/baby.asmx/SubmitOrder",                     
        data: "{'sessionid' : '"+sessionid+"',"+
              "'lang': '"+usersettings.Currlang+"',"+
              "'invoiceno': '"+invoicenr+"',"+
              "'email':'"+$j(orderids.txtOIEMAIL).val()+"',"+
              "'emailcc':'"+$j(orderids.txtOICC).val()+"'}",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            submitordercallback(msg);
        },
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
```

I get this fun error:

```
responseText: System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: sessionid.    at  
System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)    at  
System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)    at  
System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()    at  
System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

data evaluates to: `{'sessionid' : 'f61f8da737c046fea5633e7ec1f706dd','lang': 'SE','invoiceno': '11867','email':'steve@jobs.com','emailcc':''}`

Ok, fair enough, but this function from jquery communicates fine with another webservice.

Defined:

c#:

```
[WebMethod]
public string CheckoutClicked(string sessionid,string lang)
{
//*snip*

//jquery:

var divCheckoutClicked = function()
{
    $j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wservice/baby.asmx/CheckoutClicked",                     
        data: "{'sessionid': '"+sessionid+"','lang': '"+usersettings.Currlang+"'}",         
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            divCheckoutClickedCallback(msg);
        },
        error: AjaxFailed
    });     
}
```

Comment: Why are you building a JSON string within Javascript? jQuery is perfectly capable of taking a Javascript array/object and turning it into a JSON string automatically. There's no need to build one manually - consider what would happen if any of those variables you're inserting contains a quote character - *boom*

Comment: the data parameter expects a proper json object. What you've provided is a string...

Comment: He's on the right track with the string.  ASMX ScriptServices expect their input parameters in a JSON string, not as URLEncoded key/value pairs. jQuery URLEncodes the data parameter if it's an object, which isn't suitable for passing to this type of service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data: {sessionid: sessionid,
       lang: usersettings.Currlang,
       invoiceno: invoicenr,
       email: $j(orderids.txtOIEMAIL).val(),
       emailcc: $j(orderids.txtOICC).val()
        },
```

Comment: actually @Reigel's answer looks good.  but i think you still need to remove the quotes around the argument name

Comment: Thanks for your input all, removing all ' and " and + from the text worked.

  data: {sessionid : sessionid,
     lang: usersettings.Currlang,
     invoiceno: invoicenr,
     email:$j(orderids.txtOIEMAIL).val(),
     emailcc:$j(orderids.txtOICC).val()},

worked.

Comment: The most annyoing thing in this all, is that the other way works fine in other instances.  I've been using it with quotes for a while now, and never had any errors, and don't on other functions...

Comment: hmm, this is happening again, and I seem to be unable to find a solution, this time I'm posting 

 data:   {psessionid:  sessionid ,
                    pname: name,
                    pisPublic: ispublic=="on" ? 0 : 1 },

c# function is public string CreateChicken(string psessionid,string pname,int pisPublic)

Comment: Same problem, found this:
http://encosia.com/2010/05/31/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/

Answer (score 1):

Refer to http://encosia.com/2010/05/31/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/

Short version is, 
Be sure to set data as a string using this format

// RIGHT
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'WebService.asmx/Hello',
  data: '{ FirstName: "Dave", LastName: "Ward" }'
});

it has to be double quotes inside the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the JSON creation and make it less brittle by using JSON.stringify to convert a client-side object to JSON string. JSON.stringify is built into newer browsers as a native feature, and can be added to older browsers by including [Douglas Crockford's json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Take a look at this post on [using JSON and data transfer objects with ASMX ScriptServices](http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/) for some examples.  Its examples start in almost exactly the same predicament that you're currently in, so hopefully it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

remove the single quotes;

```
data: "{sessionid : "+sessionid+","+
              "lang: "+usersettings.Currlang+","+
              "invoiceno: "+invoicenr+","+
              "email:"+$j(orderids.txtOIEMAIL).val()+","+
              "emailcc:"+$j(orderids.txtOICC).val()+"}",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

and move the curly brace outside the quotes

Comment: why should the OP need to sting-ify the data? Why not pass it back as an object?

Comment: That's a requirement of ASMX ScriptServices. They expect their parameters in a single JSON string, not URLEncoded key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

data should be more like data: {sessionid : sessionid, lang: usersettin...

the way you're sending it now, it's a string.. so your application is NOT getting the variable sessionID and it's value.

Thus, it's reporting an error. this error is not json, so responseText is throwing an error.